# request soap wcf webService with android retrofit

Tags: android, wcf, soap, retrofit

hi guys how to request to implement this soap request with android retrofit but i got 400 response code is there any way to implement this with retrofit ?

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<ActivityId CorrelationId="e5bbf878-4503-4010-aab5-b81d422b66ba" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">f905b59e-f833-44cb-9760-3c6619dc8c6c</ActivityId>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
    <QueryMessage xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <messageSet xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:ActionId i:nil="true">?</a:ActionId>
            <a:Ip>::1</a:Ip>
            <a:Parameters>
                <a:Parameter>
                    <a:Name>Username</a:Name>
                    <a:Value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">tipex</a:Value>
                </a:Parameter>
                <a:Parameter>
                    <a:Name>Password</a:Name>
                    <a:Value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">123456</a:Value>
                </a:Parameter>

            </a:Parameters>
            <a:Title>Authenticate</a:Title>
            <a:Token>?</a:Token>
            <a:Username>tipex</a:Username>
        </messageSet>
    </QueryMessage>
</s:Body>
```

and this is my model classes

@Root(name = "s:Envelope")
@Namespace(prefix = "s", reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")

public class Envelope {

```
@Element(name = "s:Body")
private Body body;

public Body getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(Body body) {
    this.body = body;
}
```

}

```
@Root(name = "x:Body")
```

public class Body {

```
@Element(name = "QueryMessage")
private QueryMessage queryMessage;

public QueryMessage getQueryMessage() {
    return queryMessage;
}

public void setQueryMessage(QueryMessage queryMessage) {
    this.queryMessage = queryMessage;
}
```

}

```
@Root(name = "QueryMessage")
```

@Namespace(reference = "http://tempuri.org/")

public class QueryMessage {

```
@Element(name = "messageSet")
private MessageSet messageSet;

public MessageSet getMessageSet() {
    return messageSet;
}

public void setMessageSet(MessageSet messageSet) {
    this.messageSet = messageSet;
}
```

}

```
@Root (name = "messageSet")
```

@NamespaceList({
        @Namespace( prefix = "a", reference = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library"),
        @Namespace( prefix = "i", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
})

public class MessageSet {

```
@Element(name = "ActionId",required = false)
private String actionId;

@Element(name = "Ip")
private String ip;

@ElementList (name = "Parameters")
private List<ModelParameter> modelParameterList;

@Element(name = "Title")
private String title;

@Element(name = "Token",required = false)
private String token;

@Element(name = "Username")
private String username;


public String getActionId() {
    return actionId;
}

public void setActionId(String actionId) {
    this.actionId = actionId;
}

public String getIp() {
    return ip;
}

public void setIp(String ip) {
    this.ip = ip;
}

public List<ModelParameter> getModelParameterList() {
    return modelParameterList;
}

public void setModelParameterList(List<ModelParameter> modelParameterList) {
    this.modelParameterList = modelParameterList;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
```

}

```
@Root(name = "Parameter")
```

public class ModelParameter {

```
@Element(name = "Name")
private String name;


@Element(name = "Value")
private String value;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

[this is my web service class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTPdL.png)

Comment: What problem you are facing with above code? Describe your problem in details.

Comment: @kiranBiradar my request return error code 400 ! am i missing something???

Comment: Can you show how you are unmarshalling the xml?

Comment: @kiranBiradar my xml request as you can see at top of question return me response 200.
 i created these model as you can see below my xml request ; based on my xml request and in android studio i tested it with retrofit and i get response 400
 i guess my problem is not setting namespace to my VALUE element that i dont know how can i do it

Comment: Ok I can help you with setting namespace.

Comment: Here you are converting object to xml right?If yes can you give the code how are you converting?

Comment: @kiranBiradar let me upload my web service class photo

Comment: @kiranBiradar at the bottom you can see the webservice photo link

Comment: @kiranBiradar i am converting using SimpleXmlConverterFactory library

Comment: Are you converting xml to object or object to xml?

Comment: @kiranBiradar xml to object ! i guess the problem is here
 <a:Parameter>
                    <a:Name>Username</a:Name>
                    <a:Value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">tipex</a:Value>
                </a:Parameter>

Comment: I'm trying to compile and execute myself

Comment: Find my answer below.

Comment: @kiranBiradar thanks man 
bro do you have what' app??
if yes please send your number to hesamilyaei24@gmail.com

Comment: llyaei Yes I use whatsapp and I will share the same.
If it solves the problem please accept the answer and upvote.

Comment: @kiranBiradar bro? i think i just made mistake i want to request to service so it should not be object to xml??

Comment: To convert from object to xml below code should work with slight changes.

Comment: @kiranBiradar can you please send it too? tnx a lot

Comment: It will take some. little busy right now.

Comment: @kiranBiradar ok tnx i will wait

Comment: I have added the changes

Comment: @kiranBiradar oh you edited?? i wanted both xml to obj and obj to xml :(
can you send xml to obj in whats app?

Comment: It works for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were plenty of wrong with your classes.
I have modified and tested. I Was able to convert xml to object.

Envelope Class.

```
    /**
 * Created by kbiradar on 7/26/2018.
 */

@Root(name = "Envelope")
@Order(elements = {"Header", "Body"})
@Namespace(prefix = "s", reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
public class Envelope {

    @Element(name = "Header")
    @Namespace(prefix = "s", reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
    private Header header;

    @Element(name = "Body")
    @Namespace(prefix = "s", reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
    private Body body;

    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(Body body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public Header getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(Header body) {
        this.header = body;
    }
}
```

Header Class.

```
/**
 * Created by kbiradar on 7/26/2018.
 */

@Root(name = "Header", strict = false)
public class Header {

    static class ActivityId
    {
        @Attribute
        String CorrelationId;

        @Text
        private String ActivityId;
    }

    @Element(name = "ActivityId")
    ActivityId ActivityId;
}
```

Body Class.

```
/**
 * Created by kbiradar on 7/26/2018.
 */
@Root(name = "Body", strict = false)
public class Body {

    @Element(name = "QueryMessage")
    //@Namespace(prefix = "s", reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
    @Namespace(reference = "http://tempuri.org/")
    private QueryMessage queryMessage;

    public QueryMessage getQueryMessage() {
        return queryMessage;
    }

    public void setQueryMessage(QueryMessage queryMessage) {
        this.queryMessage = queryMessage;
    }
}
```

QueryMessage Class.

```
/**
 * Created by kbiradar on 7/26/2018.
 */

@Root(name = "QueryMessage")
public class QueryMessage {

    @Element(name = "messageSet")
    @NamespaceList({ @Namespace( prefix = "a", reference = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library"),
            @Namespace( prefix = "i", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance") })
    private MessageSet messageSet;

    public MessageSet getMessageSet() {
        return messageSet;
    }

    public void setMessageSet(MessageSet messageSet) {
        this.messageSet = messageSet;
    }
}
```

MessageSet Class.

```
/**
 * Created by kbiradar on 7/26/2018.
 */

@Root(name = "messageSet")
public class MessageSet {

    static class ActionId
    {
        @Attribute
        @Namespace(prefix = "i", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
        String nil;

        @Text
        private String actionId;
    }

    @Element(name = "ActionId")
    @Namespace(prefix = "a", reference = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library")
    ActionId actionId;

    @Element(name = "Ip")
    @Namespace(prefix = "a", reference = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library")
    private String ip;

    @ElementList(name = "Parameters")
    @Namespace(prefix = "a", reference = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library")
    private List<ModelParameter> modelParameterList;

    @Element(name = "Title")
    @Namespace(prefix = "a", reference = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library")
    private String title;

    @Element(name = "Token",required = false)
    @Namespace(prefix = "a", reference = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library")
    private String token;

    @Element(name = "Username")
    @Namespace(prefix = "a", reference = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library")
    private String username;


    public String getActionId() {
        return actionId.actionId;
    }

    public void setActionId(String actionId) {
        this.actionId.actionId = actionId;
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public List<ModelParameter> getModelParameterList() {
        return modelParameterList;
    }

    public void setModelParameterList(List<ModelParameter> modelParameterList) {
        this.modelParameterList = modelParameterList;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Message Parameter class.

```
/**
 * Created by kbiradar on 7/26/2018.
 */

@Root(name = "Parameter")
@Namespace(prefix = "a", reference = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library")
public class ModelParameter {


    static class value
    {
        @Attribute
        @Namespace(prefix = "i", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
        String type;

        @Text
        private String value;
    }

    @Element(name = "Name")
    @Namespace(prefix = "a", reference = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library")
    private String name;


    @Element(name = "Value")
    @Namespace(prefix = "a", reference = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library")
    @NamespaceList({@Namespace(prefix = "a", reference = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sanay.Suip.Library"),
    @Namespace(prefix = "b", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")})
    private value value;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value.value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value.value = value;
    }
}
```